# Cycle with FadeIn/Out on 3 divs

Tags: jquery

Hi i've made that piece of code to change the opacity of 3 divs.
The code should every 10s show the #background2, hide the #background1 and then hide the #background2 show the background 3...

```
   <div id="background1" class="backgrounds" style="opacity:1"></div>
    <div id="background2" class="backgrounds" style="opacity:0"></div>
    <div id="background3" class="backgrounds" style="opacity:0"></div>

    <style type="text/css">
        #background1{ background-image: url('<?= HTTP_PROJECT_ROOT?>/image/background/1.jpg')}
        #background2{ background-image: url('<?= HTTP_PROJECT_ROOT?>/image/background/2.jpg')}
        #background3{ background-image: url('<?= HTTP_PROJECT_ROOT?>/image/background/3.jpg')}
        .backgrounds{ background-clip: cover;width:100%;height:100%;left: 0px; top: 0px; position: fixed;z-index:-1;}
    </style>    


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nb_background = $('.backgrounds').length;
        var id_next_background,id_current_background ='';

        function reloadBackground(){

           $('.backgrounds').each(function(){
                if($(this).css("opacity")=="1"){
                    id_current_background = $(this).attr("id").replace("background","");
                    id_next_background = parseInt(id_current_background);
                    id_next_background ++ ;

                    if($("#background"+id_next_background).length==0){
                      id_next_background="1";
                    }
                }
           });

           $("#background"+id_current_background).animate({opacity:0},2000);
           $("#background"+id_next_background).animate({opacity:1},2000);
           setTimeout(reloadBackground(),10000);
        }

        $(function(){
            reloadBackground();
        });
    </script>
```

It's actually not working i get "Maximum call stack exceded" 
Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$(function(){
     setInterval(reloadBackground,1000);
});
function reloadBackground(){
  var visible = $('.backgrounds:visible');
  var index = $('.backgrounds').index(visible);
  var arraymax = $('.backgrounds').length;
  var next = index +1 >= arraymax ? 0 : index +1;
  visible.hide();
  $('.backgrounds').eq(next).show();
}
```

```css
 #background1 {
   background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/500x400/000/fff');
 }
 #background2 {
   background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/500x400/f00/fff')
 }
 #background3 {
   background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/500x400/00f/fff')
 }
 .backgrounds {
   background-clip: cover;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: -1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background1" class="backgrounds" style="display:block;"></div>
<div id="background2" class="backgrounds" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="background3" class="backgrounds" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the function reference, not executing the function in setTimeout argument 1

```
setTimeout(reloadBackground,10000); //not setTimeout(reloadBackground(),10000);
```

The better way of doing would be using `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`

```
$(function(){
     setInterval(reloadBackground,10000);
     //remove the setTimeout in function reloadBackground
});
```